# Are Array, Object, Map built-in constructor functions or classes?

Tags: javascript, function, class, constructor, built-in

In some places, they say that `Array`, `Date` and `Object` are built-in classes. However, I find that they can all be called without `new` which isn't supposed to be possible with classes.

And even though `Map`, `Set`, etc... can't be called without `new`. All of them will show something like `function ItsName() { [native code] }` while trying to get their definition while I would think a class is supposed to show something like `class ItsName { [native code] }`.

Comment: JavaScript has been evolving for a long time. Map and Set are *much* newer than Array and Date.

Comment: So because Array and Object are older, they can be called without new and Map and Set can't be called without new because it would be disrepectful to not call them new.

Comment: Well it's a little more complicated than that.  The older constructor functions have different semantics when called without `new`, and while it may be a little inelegant it makes sense. It's not clear what sort of behavior `Map()` would have without `new`. Note also that `Symbol` represents a class of items, but it *cannot* be called with `new`.  In the end, these are things that the standards committee decides, and there's nothing we can do about it.

Comment: Note that you can write your own functions to behave such that they insist on being called with `new`.

Answer (score 1):

The most specific description for objects like `Object`, `Array`, etc. is "built-in constructor".

In short, section [4.4.12 built-in object](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/overview.html#sec-built-in-object) annotates:

> **NOTE**
> Standard built-in objects are defined in this specification.
> An ECMAScript implementation may specify and supply additional kinds of
> built-in objects. A *built-in constructor* is a built-in object that is
> also a constructor.

Section 4 is non-normative, but the above note can be derived from the following:

1. **Section [6.1.7.2 Object Internal Methods and Internal Slots](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-data-types-and-values.html#sec-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots)**: (Boldness applied by me)

   > ... **A *function object* is an object** that supports
   > the `[[Call]]` internal method. A *constructor* is an object that
   > supports the `[[Construct]]` internal method. Every object that
   > supports `[[Construct]]` must support `[[Call]]`;
   > that is, **every constructor must be a function object**.
   > Therefore, a constructor may also be referred to as a
   > *constructor function* or *constructor function object*.

   This means, constructors are functions, and functions are objects.
2. **Section [6.1.7.4 Well-Known Intrinsic Objects](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-data-types-and-values.html#sec-well-known-intrinsic-objects)**:

   > Well-known intrinsics are built-in objects (...).

   And:

   > The well-known intrinsics are listed in Table 6.

   With [Table 6](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-data-types-and-values.html#table-well-known-intrinsic-objects):

   | Global Name | ECMAScript Language Association |
   | --- | --- |
   | `Array` | The Array constructor ([23.1.1](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/indexed-collections.html#sec-array-constructor)) |
   | `Object` | The Object constructor ([20.1.1](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/fundamental-objects.html#sec-object-constructor)) |
   | ... | ... |

Point 2 lists several built-in objects like `Array` and `Object`. The table and the definitions in the corresponding links call these "constructors".

Point 1 explains that constructors are objects, so it is valid to say "built-in constructor" instead of "built-in objects", where applicable.

---

Here is a short summary of other interesting terms and definitions in the specification:

- An *object* is a member of the type Object. (See [4.4.6](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/overview.html#sec-terms-and-definitions-object))
- A *function* (or *function object*) is an *object* that supports the internal function `[[Call]]` (which may or may not be exposed). (See [6.1.7.2 Table 5](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-data-types-and-values.html#function-object))
- A *constructor* (or *constructor function* or *constructor function object*) is a *function* that supports the internal function `[[Construct]]` (commonly invoked with the `new` operator). (See [6.1.7.2 Table 5](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-data-types-and-values.html#constructor))
- All *constructors* have the property `prototype`. (See [4.3.1](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/overview.html#sec-objects))
- Both *function definitions* and *function expressions* create constructors. (See [15.2.4](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-functions-and-classes.html#sec-runtime-semantics-instantiateordinaryfunctionobject) and [15.2.5](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-functions-and-classes.html#sec-runtime-semantics-instantiateordinaryfunctionexpression), respectively)
- *Arrow function expressions* do not create constructors and can therefore not be instantiated. (See [15.3.4](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-functions-and-classes.html#sec-runtime-semantics-instantiatearrowfunctionexpression))
- *Class definitions* (ES6 `class` syntax) return constructor functions that are uncallable (meaning they do not expose `[[Call]]`). (See [15.7.14](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-functions-and-classes.html#sec-runtime-semantics-classdefinitionevaluation))

Comment: I more or less understand everything you wrote except for internal function [[Construct]] and [[Call]]. What are they?

Comment: @Superhuman Much like how classes can have [private members](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields) that are inaccessible outside the class, objects can have _internal_ members that are inaccessible -to us- in JavaScript (meaning, only accessible to the core engine).